# How get the text in an element, with the images in it (JQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to get the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched elements, but with the images in it.

For example for this input:

```
<div id="test">Lorem ipsum <strong>dolor</strong> sit amet, consectetur <a href="...">adipiscing</a> elit: <img src="test.png" alt="test"/> Etiam vulputate arcu risus</div>
```

I would like to get this output:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit: <img src="test.png" alt="test"/> Etiam vulputate arcu risus
```

How is it possible to manage it using **JQuery**? It is almost the same as the `.text()` function, but I should somehow keep the images.

Comment: This will not be straight forward. You would probably be best to recurse through the nodes retrieveing textNodes and the outerHTML of DOMElements where the tagName == `IMG`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I belive i have a simple solution. Here is what you can do:

```
var source = $("#test").clone(); //clone your dom element
source.find(':not(img)').remove(); //remove all tags exept img
console.log(source.html()); //Watch result in console
```

**UPDATE:**

If you do not want to delete contents of tags:

```
$("#test").find("*").not("img").each(function() {
    $(this).replaceWith(this.innerHTML);
});
```

Here is [codepen](https://codepen.io/Teo_van_KOT/pen/XgVLga).

**UPDATE 2:**

If you have nested elements:

```
var beginsWith = function(needle, haystack){
    return (haystack.substr(0, needle.length) == needle);
};

var filterHTML = function($elem) {
    var $cp = $elem.clone();

    var changed = true;
    while(changed) {
        var tx1 = $cp.html();
        $cp.contents().each(function() {
            if(this.nodeType === Node.COMMENT_NODE) {
                $(this).remove();
            } else if(this.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                if(this.nodeName == 'IMG') {

                    var src = $(this).attr("src");

                    if(
                        !beginsWith("http://",src) &&
                        !beginsWith("https://",src) &&
                        !beginsWith("data:image",src)
                    ) {
                        $(this).remove();
                    }

                } else {
                    $(this).replaceWith(this.innerHTML);
                }

            }

        });
        var tx2 = $cp.html();
        changed = (tx1 != tx2);
    }

    return $cp.html();

};
```

Comment: Thank you. But could you explain how it works? `.remove()` should remove not just the element itself, but everything inside it

Comment: @IterAtor ok, now i get what you want. Here is another solution in update

Answer (score 1):

In the other answer it will remove all the element tags except img so if you notice, the text inside strong element (**dolor**) and anchor element (**adipiscing**) will not be displayed, use this code so you will get your expected output.

```
<div id="test">Lorem ipsum <strong>dolor</strong> sit amet, consectetur <a href="...">adipiscing</a> elit: <img src="test.png" alt="test"/> Etiam vulputate arcu risus</div>
<script>
$(function(){
var $contents = $('#test').contents();
var returnString='';
for(var i=0;i< $('#test').contents().length; i++){
if($contents[i].nodeType == 3)
     returnString = returnString + $contents[i].textContent;
else if($contents[i].nodeType != 3  && $contents[i].nodeName != 'IMG')
    returnString = returnString +   $contents[i].innerHTML;
else
  returnString = returnString +   $contents[i].outerHTML;
}
console.log(returnString);
});
</script>
```

Working Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/6h924n28/

Output: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit: img tag Etiam vulputate arcu risus